# Blazor calling SnarkJS

Tags: blazor, javascript-import, zk-snark

For SnarkJS (https://github.com/iden3/snarkjs), there's an HTML example showing how to consume their ES6 javascript library:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>

  <script src="snarkjs.min.js">   </script>
  <script>

async function calculateProof() {

    const { proof, publicSignals } =
      await snarkjs.groth16.fullProve( { a: 3, b: 11}, "circuit.wasm", "circuit_final.zkey");
      
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

This call to snarkjs.groth16.fullProve works perfectly in the browser.

In Blazor, I load snarkjs.min.js into an IJSObjectReference (myJSmodule), but I don't know how to emulate the snarkjs.groth16.fullProve call from Blazor to the module.  Something like:

```
await myJSmodule.InvokeVoidAsync("snarkjs.groth16.fullProve", args...)
```

but that produces

> Could not find 'snarkjs.groth16.fullProve'...'snarkjs' was undefined

EDIT: In the end, I had two problems:

1. Chrome was caching my embedded javascript (not the dynamically loaded modules) so running the app would result in it using outdated cached javascript.  Solution was to long-click on the Chrome refresh button, and choosing "Empty Cache and Hard Reload".  Though I'm not sure if this bodes well for deployed consumer-facing websites.
2. Dimitris' answer below took care of the second problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a helper js module that exports the `calculateProof` function:

**snarkJsInteropHelper.js**

```
export async function calculateProof() {
    const { proof, publicSignals } =
        await snarkjs.groth16.fullProve({ a: 3, b: 11 }, "circuit.wasm", "circuit_final.zkey");
}
```

Then in blazor component:

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        var module = await JS.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>(
          "import", "./snarkJsInteropHelper.js");

        await module.InvokeVoidAsync("calculateProof");
    }
}
```

Comment: I did think of that, but it's the same error, "snarkjs is not defined"

Comment: Did you add `<script src="snarkjs.min.js"></script>` inside index.html?

Comment: Just tried that way as well, same problem as when loading it into a module; "snarkjs not defined"

Comment: I created this demo project and it seems to be working fine https://github.com/Jimmys20/BlazorApp4. Give it a try if you want. You have to add your `circuit.wasm` and `circuit_final.zkey` in wwwroot folder.

Comment: Got yours to work, thank you so much!  I'm going to have to unravel my code to see how mine differs.  I'll report back once I've solved it